# Realtime DB persistence distorts data display in order

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

When I open an app I display a list of groups which have name, creationDate and etc. One of the fields is recentMessage, which value is ID which points to messages collection's message. I get that recent message by:

```
fun loadRecentMessage(param: (Message) -> Unit) {
    reference.child("/messages/$groupd/messages/$messageid")
        .addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (snapshot.value != null) {
                    // If I had a list of ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
                    // 'messageid' will show to message "5"
                    // and param will be invoked with it.
                    (snapshot.getValue(Message::class.java)?.let { param.invoke(it) })
                }
            }
    
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                // Log error
            }
        })
}
```

Now when I press on group, I navigate to messages fragment and attach childEventListener to messages and display them:

```
fun loadMsgs(data: MutableLiveData<MutableList<Message>>) {
    reference
        .child("/messages/$groupid/messages/${messageid}")
        .addChildEventListener(object : ChildEventListener {
               override fun onChildAdded(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
                   // If I have a list of messages: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
                   // and I called loadRecentMessage() before, my snapshot values comes in this order:
                   // "5", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"
                   // If I don't call that method or that method uses get(), my messages
                   // order comes in good order
                   snapshot.getValue(Message::class.java)?.let { data.addAsynchronous(it) }
               }

               override fun onChildChanged(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
                   // Empty
               }

               override fun onChildRemoved(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                   // Empty
               }

               override fun onChildMoved(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
                   // Empty
               }

               override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                   // Log error
               }
           }
        )
}
```

The problem is, that my recent message, that I have loaded before, shows up first in the list, even though, it's last. When I use `get()` instead of `addValueEventListener()` to load recent message everything is fine, but I need to keep that up to date. I think it's because the persistence had my recent message saved, thus it loads it first. How to display my messages in order, even though I have one message loaded before?

UPDATE 1:

```
// This is where param.invoke(it) comes in work:
database.getRecentMessage(groupid) {
    groupsMutableValue.addAsynchronous(it)
}

// addAsynchronous() method
fun <T> MutableLiveData<MutableList<T>>.addAsynchronous(item: T) {
    val newList = mutableListOf<T>()
    this.value?.let { newList.addAll(it) }
    newList.add(item)
    this.postValue(newList)
}

// message list from DB
"messages" : {
    "-MXSkzXdm2OxV6CC3Xl3" : {
      "messages" : {
        "-MXVeBEq5ksZfPn4BoDB" : {
          "content" : "Hi",
          "from" : "2YnfQSeBladXsD9sPEcKrhxJ6CB2"
        },
        "-MXVeJ5MBOOzl53kEEC1" : {
          "content" : "Hey",
          "from" : "2g87tAMuQSOgu7b1W0uOvKDpg3K2"
        },
        "-MXVeR6vPi7KZ8tC52EP" : {
          "content" : "Hola",
          "from" : "iLOmzFZqzVRtMb5eOC1gRRWY5Ar2"
        },
        "-MXXlQVAhbT6JBJbpIRt" : {
          "content" : "Last message",
          "from" : "2YnfQSeBladXsD9sPEcKrhxJ6CB2"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's not enough code here to say what's going on. 1) Can you edit the question to include a [single, minimal-but-complete snippet that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 2) Instead of commenting out the UI code, replace it with something that logs the offending values, so we can look at the code and its output together.

Comment: Hi, Frank, thank you for your response. I've updated the code. Will this be enough? Not sure what I can update more.

Comment: What do you mean by "display my messages in order"? Order according to what? I cannot see any orderBy() call in your code.

Comment: Hi, Alex, thanks for your response. Messages in database are already in order by ID, I just need to display them in the order they are at this moment.

Comment: 1) We have no way to know what `param.invoke(it)` and `data.addAsynchronous(it)` actually do in your code. Is there a way you can `print` something in those places to show the problem? 2) Please include the JSON from `/messages/$groupd/messages/$messageid` in your question (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I've updated the code. The problem is in loadMsgs() `onChildAdded()` method. It first loads the last message in the database then the rest. If I come back from messages to groups and to messages again, it loads correctly.